# Why is my Eloquent Relation not filling all of my objects?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a "types" table which contains only ID and Name, the relation works on the first object but returns `null` on the following objects. Here is what my JSON looks like:

```
{"id":1,"type_id":1,"name":"test1","enabled":1,"measurement_type":{"id":1,"name":"test"}},
{"id":2,"type_id":2,"name":"test2","enabled":0,"measurement_type":null}]},
{"id":3,"type_id":1,"name":"test3","enabled":1,"measurement_type":null}]}
```

Here are my relations:
MeasurementFields Model

```
    public function measurement_type() {
        return $this->belongsTo(MeasurementType::class, 'type_id');
    }
```

MeasurementTypes Model

```
    public function measurement_type() {
        return $this->belongsTo(MeasurementData::class); 
    }
```

In this Model I already have a measurement_field function which declares a belongsTo to MeasurementData (different Model) So, how do I name the new function with hasMany for types?

My Controller:

```
    public function index()
    {
        return JsonResource::collection(MeasurementField::with('measurement_type')->get());
    }
```

They all contain data, as you can see from the JSON, the relation just doesn't do anything with it.

My migrations:

```
        Schema::create('measurement_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id()->autoincrement();
            $table->string('name');
        });
```

```
        Schema::create('measurement_fields', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id()->autoincrement();
            $table->foreignId('type_id')->constrained('measurement_types');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->boolean('enabled');
        });
```

Comment: have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `measurement_type` has many `measurement_field`.

and I guess you have to put this in your `MeasurementField` Model:

```
public function measurement_type() {
        return $this->belongsTo(MeasurementType::class, 'type_id');
    }
```

Comment: I made it into a hasMany but I  am getting this as response : SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'measurement_types.type_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `measurement_types` where `measurement_types`.`type_id` in (1, 2, 3))

Comment: I edited my question to how I have my code now.

Comment: MeasurementFields Model should have measurement_type function

Comment: MeasurementType model should have measurement_field function

Comment: in measurementField model -> measurement_type function, use`$this->belongsTo`

Comment: I changed those but it still only work(like before, so only the first works and others return null) if i change type_id to id in MeasurementField Model

Comment: can you add your database schema & data in the question?

Comment: I added the schema, do you also want my other models?

Comment: no, thanks no need to them

Comment: have you changed the `measurement_type` function in measurement fields model. in your updated code, its still `hasMany` instead of `belongsTo` ??

Comment: I have, it is working somehow but I haven't defined hasMany in my MeasurementType model. Can you explain why this is? I only have a belongsTo in there from MeasurementData

Comment: Edited it to what it looks like now